# Supress bash script exiting

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use conditional logic for Helm package manager, ie. if the release is installed then helm should not install the same release, if not installed then helm should install it. So very basic conditional logic. My question though is not about Helm but rather bash scripting.

To check if Helm release is installed I'm using:

```
RELEASE_INSTALLED=$(helm status RELEASE_NAME -o json | jq -r ".info.status")
```

When it is installed then I'm getting string value `deployed` defined in `RELEASE_INSTALLED` variable. But when it is not then my bash script exits with error code `1`. I would like my script to continue executing instead of immediately exiting. Then I could build some conditional logic if basically the command above fails. How can I do that having these settings at the beginning of the script?

```
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
```

Comment: you shouldn't enable `errexit` and `pipefail` if you don't want to exit when programs get an error.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) going into detail on why `errexit` is generally a bad idea (in addition to being [deeply nonportable](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/)). Writing explicit error handling (`foo || exit`) by hand is _far_ more reliable, and easier for humans to validate during a code-read.

Comment: (...the number of ways `set -e` corner-case behavior has changed over bash's history is far longer and more varied than I can keep in my head, and I'm well-represented in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/topusers; are you sure the people reviewing your code are going to do any better at remembering exactly how it's going to behave on the specific release you're targeting?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression.

```
RELEASE_INSTALLED=$(helm status RELEASE_NAME -o json | jq -r ".info.status" || echo 'not deployed')
```

`errexit` and `pipefail` don't apply if the failing command is part of a conditional expression.